# Stacking Multiple 2x2 Columns into Two Columns in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

_Hi, I have a table with multiple 2x2 columns (2&4, 6&8...), and I would like to stack those pairs into a two columns table while maintaining the correspondence. The output should be :

```
col2 | col4  
col6 | col8
```

| Column2 | Column4 | Column6 | Column8 | Column10 | Column12 | Column14 | Column16 | Column18 | Column20 | Column22 | Column24 | Column26 | Column28 | Column30 | Column32 | Index |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.1APte | 719141 | 2.19.1 | 13757 | 2.22.1 | 25169 | 2.29.1 | 59756 | 2.37.1 | 28892 | 2.45.1 | 27559 | 2.52.1 | 25981 | 2.58.1 | 13838 | 1 |
| 0.1AHPH | 3972485 | 2.19.2 | 100596 | 2.22.2 | 206710 | 2.29.2 | 113129 | 2.37.2 | 29922 | 2.45.2 | 14862 | 2.52.2 | 117860 | 2.58.2 | 9099 | 2 |
| 0.1AHCH | 2181012 | 2.19.3 | 50851 | 2.22.3 | 78663 | 2.29.3 | 25093,5 | 2.37.3 | 20291,4 | 2.45.3 | 24622 | 2.52.3 | 3969,35 | 2.58.3 | 3859,5 | 3 |
| 0.1AHPE | 5850951 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 4 |
| 0.1AHCE | 2623078 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 5 |
| 0.1RPte | 102186 | 2.21.1 | 447467 | 2.27.1 | 34524 | 2.35.1 | 6872,6 | 2.43.1 | 7106,3 | 2.50.1 | 15506,9 | 2.56.1 | 1509,54 | 2.62.1 | 4620,6 | 6 |
| 0.1RHPH | 504274 | 2.21.2 | 247933 | 2.27.2 | 13605 | 2.35.2 | 83707 | 2.43.2 | 9802 | 2.50.2 | 15855 | 2.56.2 | 8735 | 2.62.2 | 6686 | 7 |
| 0.1RHCH | 245013 | 2.21.3 | 167623 | 2.27.3 | 7067 | 2.35.3 | 4936,4 | 2.43.3 | 2360,7 | 2.50.3 | 998,3 | 2.56.3 | 5254,1 | 2.62.3 | 1443,77 | 8 |
| 0.1RHPE | 603041 | 2.21.4 | 9416 | 2.27.4 | 4539,09 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 9 |
| 0.1RHCE | 176346 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 10 |
| 1A | 15015887 | 2.20.1 | 7414 | 2.23.1 | 54168 | 2.30.1 | 91816 | 2.38.1 | 44462 | 2.46.1 | 64432 | 2.53.1 | 13721 | 2.59.1 | 12839 | 11 |
| 1R | 2017513 | 2.20.2 | 15715 | 2.23.2 | 91088 | 2.30.2 | 48382 | 2.38.2 | 10127 | 2.46.2 | 54120 | 2.53.2 | 47040 | 2.59.2 | 64977 | 12 |
| null | null | 2.20.3 | 5451,2 | 2.23.3 | 34985,1 | 2.30.3 | 9680,66 | 2.38.3 | 16083,7 | 2.46.3 | 13806,6 | 2.53.3 | 830,21 | 2.59.3 | 5309,42 | 13 |
| null | null | null | null | null | null | 2.30.4 |  | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 14 |
| null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 15 |
| 2.1 | 4499234 | null | null | 2.24.1 | 13109 | 2.31.1 | 83690 | 2.39.1 | 78792 | 2.47.1 | 14548 | 2.54.1 | 9029 | 2.60.1 | 15176 | 16 |
| 2.1.1 | 470703 | null | null | 2.24.2 | 24882 | 2.31.2 | 99128 | 2.39.2 | 59697 | 2.47.2 | 30047 | 2.54.2 | 9221 | 2.60.2 | 13163 | 17 |
| 2.1.2 | 197983 | null | null | 2.24.3 | 11697,8 | 2.31.3 | 32974,5 | 2.39.3 | 25628,31 | 2.47.3 | 26269,1 | 2.54.3 | 510,5 | 2.60.3 | 0 | 18 |
| 2.1.3 | 540625 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 19 |
| 2.1.4 | 586121 | null | null | 2.28.1 | 43929 | 2.36.1 | 3578,9 | 2.44.1 | 7336,9 | 2.51.1 | 4538,46 | 2.57.1 | 4833 | 2.63.1 | 205 | 20 |
| - | 15417 | null | null | 2.28.2 | 6865 | 2.36.2 | 14440 | 2.44.2 | 8965 | 2.51.2 | 11613 | 2.57.2 | 5101 | 2.63.2 | 1770 | 21 |
| - | 0 | null | null | 2.28.3 | 2503,9 | 2.36.3 | 356,4 | 2.44.3 | 4302,9 | 2.51.3 | 1072,4 | 2.57.3 | 901 | 2.63.3 | 0 | 22 |
| - | 14807 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 23 |
| - | 0 | null | null | 2.25.1 | 106004 | 2.32.1 | 30008 | 2.40.1 | 27411 | 2.48.1 | 9420 | 2.55.1 | 15818 | 2.61.1 | 12877 | 24 |
| 2.2 | 75353 | null | null | 2.25.2 | 73211 | 2.32.2 | 13865 | 2.40.2 | 21162 | 2.48.2 | 10360 | 2.55.2 | 73194 | 2.61.2 | 16574 | 25 |
| 2.3 | 1047220 | null | null | 2.25.3 | 88667,8 | 2.32.3 | 27198,3 | 2.40.3 | 24432,8 | 2.48.3 | 1871,26 | 2.55.3 | 19610,1 | 2.61.3 | 6391,8 | 26 |
| 2.64 | 52959 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 27 |
| 2.65 | 49640 | null | null | null | null | 2.33.1 | 18455 | 2.41.1 | 12055 | 2.49.1 | 23720 | null | null | null | null | 28 |
| 2.66 | 7508,44 | null | null | null | null | 2.33.2 | 41280 | 2.41.2 | 4613 | 2.49.2 | 49549 | null | null | null | null | 29 |
| 2.67 | 14939 | null | null | null | null | 2.33.3 | 7027,8 | 2.41.3 | 8984,7 | 2.49.3 | 29086,6 | null | null | null | null | 30 |
| 2.68 | 7109 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 31 |
| 2.4 | 11776 | null | null | null | null | 2.34.1 | 22459 | 2.42.1 | 17352 | null | null | null | null | null | null | 32 |
| 2.5 | 25060 | null | null | null | null | 2.34.2 | 24207 | 2.42.2 | 14739 | null | null | null | null | null | null | 33 |
| 2.6 | 19052 | null | null | null | null | 2.34.3 | 17805,4 | 2.42.3 | 13523 | null | null | null | null | null | null | 34 |
| 2.7 | 17872 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 35 |
| 2.8 | 32964 | null | null | 2.26.1 | 293304 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 36 |
| 2.9 | 10844 | null | null | 2.26.2 | 478994 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 37 |
| 2.10 | 10657 | null | null | 2.26.3 | 227270 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 38 |
| 2.11 | 15348 | null | null | 2.26.4 | 445808 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 39 |
| 2.12 | 6773 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 40 |
| 2.13 | 1449,3 | null | null | Phytoconrole | 1365,09 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 41 |
| 2.14 | 55,1 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 42 |
| 2.15 | 4021,2 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 43 |
| 2.16 | 740027 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 44 |
| 2.17 | 434193 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 45 |
| 2.18 | 0 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 46 |
| 2.69 | 437517 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | 47 |

Currently, my M code looks like this :

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(Paramètre2, null, true),
    #"ELEC 10 (2)_Sheet" = Source{[Item="ELEC 10 (2)",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Colonnes supprimées" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"ELEC 10 (2)_Sheet",{"Column40", "Column41", "Column42", "Column43", "Column44", "Column45", "Column46", "Column47", "Column48", "Column49", "Column50", "Column51", "Column52", "Column53", "Column54", "Column55", "Column56", "Column57", "Column58", "Column59", "Column60", "Column61", "Column62", "Column63", "Column5", "Column10", "Column15", "Column20", "Column25", "Column30", "Column35"}),
    #"Rempli vers le bas" = Table.FillDown(#"Colonnes supprimées",{"Column1", "Column6", "Column11", "Column16", "Column21", "Column26", "Column31", "Column36"}),
    #"Table transposée" = Table.Transpose(#"Rempli vers le bas"),
    #"Rempli vers le bas1" = Table.FillDown(#"Table transposée",{"Column1"}),
    #"Colonnes supprimées1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Rempli vers le bas1",{"Column2"}),
    #"Table transposée1" = Table.Transpose(#"Colonnes supprimées1"),
    #"Colonnes supprimées2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Table transposée1",{"Column1", "Column3", "Column5", "Column7", "Column9", "Column11", "Column13", "Column15", "Column17", "Column19", "Column21", "Column23", "Column25", "Column27", "Column29", "Column31"}),
    #"Premières lignes supprimées" = Table.Skip(#"Colonnes supprimées2",1),
    #"Index ajouté" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Premières lignes supprimées", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type)
in
    #"Index ajouté"
```

What additional code would be needed to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome.  You need to edit your question to post sample data and sample desired output, describing clearly how to get from input to output. Otherwise, I don't think anyone is going be able to help you

Comment: Thanks ! It's done. Is it much clearer ?

Comment: Please edit your question to post the source data **as text which can be copy/pasted**. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question), perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Done ! Is it workable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to remove the index column first, but you can use this pasted into home ... advanced editor ...

change the groupsof number for number of columns you want to stack as a group, and change the base_columns number to be the number of leading columns you want to preserve before stacking the other columns

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
base_columns=0, groupsof=2, //change as needed
Combo = List.Transform(List.Split(List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base_columns),groupsof), each List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),base_columns) & _),
#"Added Custom" =List.Accumulate(Combo, #table({"Column1"}, {}), (state,current)=> state & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(Source, current)),1))
in #"Added Custom"
```

[image]

in your particular case

```
    #"Premières lignes supprimées" = Table.Skip(#"Colonnes supprimées2",1),
    base_columns=0, groupsof=2, //change as needed
    Combo = List.Transform(List.Split(List.Skip(Table.ColumnNames(#"Premières lignes supprimées"),base_columns),groupsof), each List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Premières lignes supprimées"),base_columns) & _),
    #"Added Custom" =List.Accumulate(Combo, #table({"Column1"}, {}), (state,current)=> state & Table.Skip(Table.DemoteHeaders(Table.SelectColumns(#"Premières lignes supprimées", current)),1))
    in #"Added Custom"
```